# Перенос сборки gulp в новый проект

Tags: gulp

В общем, собрал сборку `Gulp`, завершил работу над проектом и теперь мне нужно начать новый.

Так собственно вопрос в чем, у меня есть файл `gulpfile.js`, с помощью которого я создал сборку и там много кода, каким образом мне эту сборку внедрить в новый проект? то есть это же глупо заново устанавливать все пакеты  в свою сборку, т.е. снова создавать этот `gulpfile`

Answer (score 0):

1. Перенести папку #srcи файлы  gulpfile.js и package.json в новый проект
2. Открыть папку с проектом в редакторе кода
3. Запускаем терминал (проверить путь к проекту) и прописать
   npm i
4. В терминале запустить gulp командой gulp